# Multiple words frequency count in string

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a text file and want the frequency count of two sets of words. for example:

```
setone <- ("mumbai", "delhi", "chennai")

settwo <- ("nike", "zara","puma")

textfile <- ("brands in cites like nike zara and puma in mumbai, delhi and chennai. while many exotic brands in mumbai... disel, durby, Calvin Kline")
```

Output required in following manner :

```
File Name   setone     settwo   Total
Textfile      4          3       7
```

Please help.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and be sure to read [MCVE] as it will help you to avoid getting your questions closed!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

setone <- c("mumbai", "delhi", "chennai")

settwo <- c("nike", "zara","puma")

textfile <- (
  "brands in cites like nike zara and puma in mumbai, delhi and chennai. 
  while many exotic brands in mumbai... disel, durby, Calvin Kline")

out <- tibble(
  textfile = textfile,
  setone = str_count(textfile, str_c(setone, collapse = '|')),
  settwo = str_count(textfile, str_c(settwo, collapse = '|'))
)
out <- mutate(out, total = setone + settwo)
```